# How to delete an attribute from a list of JSON, if possible without jQuery?

Tags: javascript, json

I tried this but doesn't help. For loop doesn't iterate even once.

```
for(var i = 0; i < $scope.recordList1.length; i++) {
    delete $scope.recordList1[i].attributes;
}
```

JSON:-

```
[{"attributes":{"type":"Contact","url":"/services/data/v30.0/sobjects/Contact/0039000000wvt6yAAA"},"Name":"Stella Pavlova","Phone":"(212) 842-5500","CreatedDate":"2014-05-15T06:17:48.000+0000","Id":"0039000000wvt6yAAA"},
{"attributes":{"type":"Contact","url":"/services/data/v30.0/sobjects/Contact/0039000000wvt6zAAA"},"Name":"Lauren Boyle","Phone":"(212) 842-5500","CreatedDate":"2014-05-15T06:17:48.000+0000","Id":"0039000000wvt6zAAA"},
{"attributes":{"type":"Contact","url":"/services/data/v30.0/sobjects/Contact/0039000000wvt70AAA"},"Name":"Babara Levy","Phone":"(503) 421-7800","CreatedDate":"2014-05-15T06:17:48.000+0000","Id":"0039000000wvt70AAA"},
{"attributes":{"type":"Contact","url":"/services/data/v30.0/sobjects/Contact/0039000000wvt71AAA"},"Name":"Josh Davis","Phone":"(503) 421-7800","CreatedDate":"2014-05-15T06:17:48.000+0000","Id":"0039000000wvt71AAA"},
{"attributes":{"type":"Contact","url":"/services/data/v30.0/sobjects/Contact/0039000000wvt72AAA"},"Name":"Jane Grey","Phone":"(520) 773-9050","CreatedDate":"2014-05-15T06:17:48.000+0000","Id":"0039000000wvt72AAA"}]
```

Comment: Works fine for me ~ http://jsfiddle.net/BTdME/

Comment: @Phil does it iterate 5 times & also removes 'attributes' ?

Comment: How do you know the loop isn't iterating? Why do you need a loop, why not just `$scope.recordList1 = []` to remove all the entries from the array?

Comment: @Barmar it needs to remove only 'attributes', rest of the properties should not be removed. regarding first question, added a console.log statement in for loop which doesn't print anything.

Comment: @Ganesh I added a jsFiddle example to my first comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're saying the for loop doesn't iterate. Does the length positive? Maybe you are looping on the data before it was filled. Try to log the array length and see. Maybe your data is overwritten somewhere.

Anyway, you could use the array method forEach - that way you don't need the i counter.

```
arr.forEach(function(value){
    delete value.attributes;
});
```